# Pre-requisites for studying zeta functions

Tags: soft-question, zeta-functions

I want to start reading about zeta functions on my own, so i want to know what are the pre requisites that i need?

P.S : I am an EE engineer and have done the basic college level mathematical courses.

Comment: I would say Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis would be a good start - do lots of exercises. Then look into Complex Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi, it has a chapter devoted to $\zeta(s)$ and the prime number theorem.  These are both rigorous mathematical texts though, not exactly "casual" reading.

Comment: Zeta functions of number fields? Zeta functions of algebraic varieties? Zeta functions of graphs? Zeta functions of dynamical systems?

Comment: which one should i start with considering i have only done calculus, vector calculus, pde,ode, linear algebra, complex analysis courses as basics in college?

Comment: That would depend on why you want to start reading about zeta functions. What have you heard about zeta functions that makes you want to start reading about them?

Comment: well, this pdf and various other related readings regarding reimann hypothesis got me interested ( http://wstein.org/rh/rh/rh.pdf ) , but the thing is i have had to make myselt contempt with mostly almost non mathematical explanations/articles regarding the reimann hypothesis,  so i would like to learn more.. Now can you give me a direction gerry?

Comment: @b555 You need complex analysis and for this, probably more analysis than you already know, so the first comment by icurays1 is exactly what you need.